# Trying to make a color picker for text. how do I apply the colorPicker function to the text I want and where?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Trying to make a color picker for text. How do I apply the colorPicker function to the text I want and where?

```
addToDoButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("toDoContainer");
  function changeColor(color) {
    // set font to theme color
    document.getElementById("toDoContainer").style.color = color;
  }
  paragraph.classList.add("paragraph-styling");
  paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
  paragraph.style.fontSize = "50px";
  paragraph.changeColor(color);
  toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
  inputField.value = " ";
  paragraph.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
    toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
  });
  paragraph.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
    toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry, I'm not really clear what outcome you desire and where you're stuck. Could you add more details, maybe explain the use case a bit further and add a bit of HTML? Thanks.

Comment: Hey ggorlen, no worries! already fixed the problem. thanks for asking for clarification though, will keep in mind the next time I ask a question to give it more thought!

Comment: Great.  Please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others with the same problem as you can benefit from your knowledge. This website is intended as a long-term resource for future visitors, so you can still make a contribution to the community by improving/clarifying your question.